# Google feed apiで取得したpublishedDateがずれる

Tags: javascript

何気ない質問なんですが、Chormeで下記のURLを打ち込むとpublishedDateが本来のものと16時間ほどずれて取得してしまいます。

本来の情報を取得することはできないでしょうか、それともこういう仕様なんでしょうか？

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://rss.itmedia.co.jp/rss/2.0/news_bursts.xml&num=8&hl=ja
```

Comment: 直接見て貰えばお判りかと思いますが、`"publishedDate":"Sat, 01 Aug 2015 15:23:00 -0700"`となっていますので、標準時より7時間遅れています。これはアメリカやカナダなどで採用されているタイムゾーンで、日本のタイムゾーンは`JST`(+9時間)です。そのため、タイムゾーンを考慮しないと `9 - (-7) = 16` 時間ずれることになります。

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。
なるほど、そういうことでしたか、、

日本の時間に直すにはプログラム側で+16時間してやるしか方法は無いでしょうか？

Comment: JavaScript には日時情報をローカルのタイムゾーンに合わせて変更する関数があったと記憶しています。私は詳しくないので分かりませんが、その点を質問に追加して新たに回答を募ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: > argusさん
ちょっとググってみます、それでもわからなかったらまた質問を上げ直します！
ありがとうございました。